# Problem inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$. Prove that $$a^3+b^3+c^3+2abc \ge a^2+b^2+c^2+2$$
I can solve it, I let $(a+b+c;ab+bc+ca;abcc)=(p;q;r)$. I need another solution

Comment: Can you show _your_ solution? (work is expected to be shown)

Comment: https://scontent.fdad2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/35925261_710096329325478_6017187561800204288_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=a835d1e2618fe723243a23bd11084645&oe=5BE9A730 It is long and write in Vietnamese, do you know that??

Comment: No, I don't know Vietnamese, but thanks for posting the image. Is the image actually your work, or is it from a book or handout?

Comment: I take problem from a book and solution by me

Comment: If that's your work, then it's impressive.

Comment: But I think it is ugly and I need another solution

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Can you help me

Comment: Consider $a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc-a^2-b^2-c^2-2$. You can do lagrange multipliers to find the minima. It is 0, at a=1, b=1, c=1. Try Minimize[{x^3+y^3+z^3+2xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2-2, x+y+z=3, x>0,y>0,z>0},{x,y,z}] at Mathematica website.

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that
$$27(a^3+b^3+c^3+2abc)\geq9(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(a+b+c)^3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(27a^3+18abc-9a^3-9a^2b-9a^2c-2a^3-6a^2b-6a^2c-4abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(16a^3-15a^2b-15a^2c+14abc)\geq0$$ or
$$15\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)+\sum_{cyc}(a^3-abc)\geq0,$$
which is true by Schur and AM-GM.

Comment: Well, schur is nice but AM-GM can solve it and very ugly :D

Comment: @Unruly Kid By AM-GM $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3=a^3+b^3+c^3\geq3abc=\sum\limits_{cyc}abc.$ Why it's very ugly?

Comment: No no, I use AM-GM to solve my problem and it is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Can't edit my comment & links don't post correctly -- so, posting it here again as an answer with minor typo corrected. Consider $a^3+b^3+c^3+2abc−a^2−b^2−c^2−2$. You can use [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) to find the minima. It is 0, at a=1, b=1, c=1.

Try Minimize[{x^3+y^3+z^3+2xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2-2, x+y+z=3, x>0,y>0,z>0},{x,y,z}] at [Mathematica website](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).